# What is this freshwater microorganism?

Tags: species-identification, microscopy

[image]Can anyone help us identify this microorganism?
Location: muddy pond water in the Santa Monica Mountains.
Size: For size reference, I think that's a euglena on its lower left.
Behavior: It was moving around, getting caught up on various other microorganisms and dragging them with it.

We are very new to this, and it doesn't look like anything else we've seen so far. Thank you!

Comment: Paramecium or Stentor? just a wild guess based on size

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We did see some paramecium and they looked different to me. The only stentor images I'm seeing have a different shape. Are there more oval-like stentors? This has that zipper-like groove all along the bottom of it, and a neat row of round brown dots along the groove.

Comment: Stentors can look oval sometimes. However, in case you saw them moving around, they should have their typical 'trumpet' shape. If you say it has a groove then I tend more towards Paramecium. What makes you think it looks different to the ones you saw?

Comment: The ones I think we saw on the same slide were more clear. We could see distinct vacuoles and an oral groove that went halfway across it. They also were less peanut shaped. And this unknown organism was rigid when it moved, so it just looked like a floating log, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the the new photo and descriptive comment. I think it is *Euglena sanguinea*. The color comes from astaxanthin. They are super interesting when it comes to light adaptation and their production of the toxin euglenophycin.